# Radiation time vs. half life period

Tags: nuclear

Is radiation time the same thing as half life period?

Also, if I'm talking about excited species in a gas, how would the gas interaction affect the radiation time, are there some formulas/approaches?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'radiation time'?

Comment: Radiation time might have to do something with Mean Half time of the radioactive decay?

Answer (score 4):

In the context of photochemistry, *radiation time* or *half life period* are not used, as far as I know.

The only relevant technical term i'm aware of -in that context- is *half-life (time)*, which describes the time needed for the concentration of an excited species to decrease to 50% of the initial value, *cf.* S. E. Braslavsky, Glossary of terms used in photochemistry,
*Pure Appl. Chem.*, **2007**, *79*, 293-465
[[DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac200779030293)].

For longer-lived excited triplet states in the gas phase, radiationless deactivation upon collision with a ground-state molecules will play a role.

Thus, the lifetime *might* be correlated with the *mean free path* of the molecules.

Comment: You missed the lifetime of a radioactive species, which works on the natural logarithm (e) instead of base 2. It is normally represented by tau.

Comment: @Canageek You're absolutely right! I only thought in electronically excited species. I guess i'm still a bit biased ;)

Comment: I worked in a radiochem lab last summer, so I had to work with both systems when looking things up.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of radioactivity (which might be what you meant by “radiation”), the [*half-life* of a radionuclide](http://goldbook.iupac.org/H02717.html) is a well-defined term and commonly used. *“Radiation time”*, on the other hand, is not used to describe radionuclides.